# Google Sheets - copy 2 spreadsheets into specific folder with specific name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have spreadsheet with multiple sheets inside. I'd like to make a macro which would copy two specific sheets into another spreadsheet and name it using format "MYNAME_YYYY_MM_DD" where YYYY_MM_DD is replaced with the date on which macro was ran.

So far i have this:

```
function X() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('INPUT'), true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('OUTPUT'), true);
 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy two spreadsheets into a folder

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss0 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id0");
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id1");
  const file0 = DriveApp.getFileById(ss0.getId());
  const file1 = DriveApp.getFileById(ss1.getId());
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  file0.makeCopy(`myname${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyy_MM_dd")}`,folder);
  file0.makeCopy(`myname${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyy_MM_dd")}`,folder);
}
```